# laravel can't print the correct parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this function

```
public function show($id)
    {
        echo $id;exit;
        $restaurant = Restaurant::find($id);
        return View::Make('restaurants.profile')->with('restaurant', $restaurant);
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
http://localhost:8082/profjectname/public/restaurants/show/20
```

I got this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

when I call it this way:

```
http://localhost:8082/ParkingProject/public/restaurants/show?id=3
```

it prints `show` instead of `3`

when I call it this way:

```
http://localhost:8082/ParkingProject/public/restaurants/testestestes?id=3
```

it prints `testestestes` instead of `3`

#### routes.php

I have this :

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

the routes already works for other functions in the controller, so I don't thing the route has any error.

could you help me please

Comment: Why don't you have a vhost set up? You can't use some php/laravel/symfony functions when you don't use the vhost.

Comment: Btw, obviously you are not using the right functions, in Symfony/laravel, parameters are like this: **.../public/restaurants/testestestes/id/3** -> using '/' and not '?'

Comment: @Xatenev I don't know what vhost is, however, everything is working with me until now. So, I guess the problem is not with this `vhost` :)

Comment: @Xatenev nice idea. should I use `restaurnsts/id/3` instead of `restaurants/show/3` ?

Comment: @Xatenev not the exact way, it should be `restaurants/3` as the first answer stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using resource controller, there's no need to put the `show` in your url, e.g.

```
http://localhost:8082/profjectname/public/restaurants/20
```

See [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)

So for your resource controller `restaurants`:

```
Verb   Path                           Action        Route Name
GET    /restaurants                   index         resource.index
GET    /restaurants/create            create        resource.create
POST   /restaurants                   store         resource.store
GET    /restaurants/{restaurant_id}   show          resource.show
```

Comment: no I need it plural, I don't want it single. instead, I want it plural, it shouldn't matter bty, I already call it `restaurants` and the routs is for `restaurants`

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I understood it incorrectly, updated my answer.

Comment: yes that works, +1, I will accept your answer when the system allows. many thanks

Comment: but still there is something wrong going on. when I do this: $restaurant->$id it gives me an empty result, though I already have the `id` column in my database. but when I try `$restaurant->name` i got property not found though the name column is already exist, could u help please?

Comment: Is `$restaurant->id` a comment typo? Try `$restaurant->id`.

Comment: yes yes a typo, the problem is not syntax :) though I am a beginner in laravel but I have been programing since I was 17

Comment: Hmm. I think that deserves to be its own question then.

Comment: I am not able to post another question, because I need to wait for like 90 minutes to post a new question since I dont have a good reputation. However, I will keep looking for this problem. than

Comment: Sorry but it's hard to help here because I would be asking a whole another set of code. Probably violate SO rules too.